# Python: XML parsing using xml.dom.minidom - iterating over collection.getElementsByTagName

Tags: python, xml

I have some xml I'm trying to parse using Python 2.7.  The XML is in the format below.  In the code (also included below), if I try to print using `collection.getAttribute('ProjectId')` I get the id number, but once I assign collection to `tags` and then run it through a loop, I don't get output(no error message).  Any clues?

XML:

```
<SummaryReport ProjectId="37f8d135-1f1d-4e57-9b7d-b084770c6bf5" EntityId="016fbc07-69f0-407e-b5b5-0b0b6bba4307" Status="Failed">
  <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
  <SuccessfulCount>0</SuccessfulCount>
  <FailedCount>0</FailedCount>
  <StartUtcTime>2015-09-09T16:43:11.810715Z</StartUtcTime>
  <EndUtcTime>2015-09-09T16:43:44.5418427Z</EndUtcTime>
  <IsIncremental>false</IsIncremental>
  <OnDemand>true</OnDemand>
  <TrackingId>c0972936-c8b6-4cdb-b089-d08c6f9702aa</TrackingId>
  <Message>An error occurred during content building: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index</Message>
  <LogEntries>
    <LogEntry>
      <Level>Info</Level>
      <LogCodeType>System</LogCodeType>
      <LogCode>PhaseSucceedInfo</LogCode>
      <Name>Phase</Name>
      <Message>'Load Metadata' succeeded in 00:00:00.1905878 seconds.</Message>
      <Anchor>Info_7333babe-fc51-4b45-9167-bf263e7babcb</Anchor>
    </LogEntry>
    <LogEntry>
     <Level>Info</Level>
     <LogCodeType>System</LogCodeType>
     <LogCode>PublishRequest</LogCode>
     <Name>PublishTocAndArticleInit</Name>
     <Message>'Load Metadata' succeeded in 00:00:01.1905878 seconds.</Message>
     <Anchor>Info_51c10e71-d99a-49f9-b4aa-d83dc273426a</Anchor>
     </LogEntry>
  </LogEntries> 
</SummaryReport>
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("file.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

#Get all the tags under summaryreport
tags = collection.getElementsByTagName("SummaryReport")


#print tag info
for tag in tags:
    print '*******Tag Info************'

    print 'Project Id: %s' % tag.getAttribute('ProjectId')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no output because `collection.getElementsByTagName("SummaryReport")` returns nothing :

```
>>> tags = collection.getElementsByTagName("SummaryReport")
>>> print(tags)
[]
```

That make sense since `collection` already reference `SummaryReport` element and it has no descendant element named the same.

**UPDATE :**

Simple `for` loop works fine to iterate through `Level` elements and print the value, for example :

```
>>> tags = collection.getElementsByTagName("Level")
>>> for tag in tags:
        print(tag.firstChild.nodeValue)
Info
Info
```

Comment: Thanks. When i try to adjust the code `for collection in collections`, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "xmlparser.py", line 12, in <module>`
    `for collection in collections:`
`TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`                     

From reading, it looks like I'm trying to iterate over the object, which is not possible, but am at lost as to how to fix.

Comment: @DBS You only have one `SummaryReport`, so you cant do `for` loop (and you don't need to). Simply use `collection.getAttribute('ProjectId')` as you know

Comment: Thanks.  I get that, but I will have instances such as the 'Level' tag that are repeated in the xml and if i try to iterate over it using `collection.getElementsByTagName('Level')`, I get the same error message, `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`

Comment: @DBS You should be able to iterate over `collection.getElementsByTagName('Level')`. Anyway, if that's the actual problem, please ask so in the question (post sample XML that has multiple `Level` tags, and post the corresponding python codes)

Comment: I expanded the XML with multiple `Level` tags and adjusted the question. Thanks

Comment: @DBS see the **update** section above. The scenario is a bit different since `Level` elements don't have `ProjectId`, so the example print the element's value instead